# An instance of the service developed by Quarkus was restarted due to a specific error

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

An instance of the service developed by Quarkus was restarted due to a specific error, as shown below. I am currently unable to understand the root cause and the solution to resolve it.
Not sure if this error is coming from the framework?
This issue happens randomly. After that, the service can start normally, but sometimes the issue occurs again.
Currently, I am using Quarkus version 3.6.0 and Java 17 to develop the service.

**=====Error log=====**

```
siginfo: si_signo: 7, si_code: 4, si_addr: 0x00007fbc41571000
Current timestamp: 1702948154532
General purpose register values:
  RAX 0x00007fbc41571618 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fbc10000b80
  [ [ SubstrateSegfaultHandler caught a segfault in thread 0x00007fbc10000b80 ] ]
  siginfo: si_signo: 7, si_code: 4, si_addr: 0x00007fbc41571618
General purpose register values:
  RAX 0x00007fbc41571618 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fbc10000b80
  [ [ SubstrateSegfaultHandler caught a segfault in thread 0x00007fbc10000b80 ] ]
  siginfo: si_signo: 7, si_code: 4, si_addr: 0x00007fbc41571618
General purpose register values:
  RAX 0x00007fbc41571618 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fbc10000b80
  RIP 0x000000000076e70f points into AOT compiled code 
Printing Instructions (ip=0x000000000076e70f):
Top of stack (sp=0x00007fbc1d7f8240):
Top frame info:
  TotalFrameSize in CodeInfoTable 80
Threads:
VM thread locals for the failing thread 0x00007fbc10000b80:
No VMOperation in progress
The 15 most recent VM operation status changes (oldest first):
Counters:
Java frame anchors for the failing thread 0x00007fbc10000b80:
  No anchors
Stacktrace for the failing thread 0x00007fbc10000b80:
VM mutexes:
  mutex "thread" is locked by thread 0x00007fbc50000b80
  mutex "mainVMOperationControlWorkQueue" is locked by thread 0x00007fbc50000b80
  mutex "referencePendingList" is unlocked. 
AOT compiled code is mapped at 0x0000000000407000 - 0x000000000291c38f
Heap settings and statistics:
  Supports isolates: true
  Heap base: 0x00007fbc9d600000
  Object reference size: 8
  Aligned chunk size: 1048576
  Incremental collections: 6216146
  Complete collections: 47077
Native image heap boundaries:
Heap:
Segfault detected, aborting process. Use runtime option -R:-InstallSegfaultHandler if you don't want to use SubstrateSegfaultHandler.
```